# Attempting to start MySQL service

Tags: mysql

I installed xampp on c:/xampp, I started apache it started well when I started MySQL this happened [this what happend][image: 1]

and stayed like this forever
tried the "services.msc" and changing port
didn't work

Comment: Did you have MySQL Server installed before you installed XAMPP and mariaDB

Answer (score 0):

I had MySQL before and I already uninstalled it but I had same problem , I tried all other ways like changing port "3306" to another , it didn't actually worked though! So here's the solution worked for me. Run Command Prompt as Administrators then type :

```
C:\Windows\system32>**sc delete mysql**
```

It must be answered SECUSS. then open your task manager and find MYSQL , click on it then click on "End task" at the bottom right. then close XAMPP and re-open it.
I hope it works for you too!